# fft on samples of an audio file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to extract information from a sound file in order to use it in a video classification algorithm I'm working on.

My problem is that I don't know how to work exactly with audio files in Matlab.

Below is what I need to accomplish:

- open the audio file and get the sampling rate/frequency
- I need to work on a window of 2 seconds so I have to loop over the file and get each 2 seconds as a window and then do the ftt (Fast-Fourier-Transform) on each window.

After that it is my turn to use these values to do what I want

any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning on windowing your two second samples? Otherwise you may end up with artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code may only give you some idea. You may need to determine another fft size, a windowing function like hamming etc.

To read a wav file:

```
[data, Fs] = wavread('path.wav');
```

Splitting to 2 sec windows and getting fft:

```
frameFFT = [];
timeStep = Fs*2;
for i=1:timeStep:length(data)-timeStep
   frameFFT = [frameFFT; fft(data(i:i+timeStep-1),1024)];
end
```

Comment: I'm working with mp3 file so I can't use wavread, I tried data = dsp. AudioFileReader("..."); but the length(data)  is one, I'm not sure why it is like this

Comment: Also I used data = audioread("..");  but data does not seem a vector because I checked its size and it is [4186368 2], any idea about it?

Comment: @Maystro, audio file may be 2 channel, you can take only the first column as input.

Comment: @Maystro, it depends on how the original record is taken. it may be a real stereo or just same signals on the different channels, to be on the safe side you can take the average of the two as proposed in the link: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/converting-from-stereo-to-mono-by-averaging

Comment: I get it now, most of audio file should have 2 channels (left, right) and the data in both channels most likely will be the same

Comment: Actually, I have one more question, Since we hear the same sound on the left and right channel that mean they should have the same value in the 2 channels but it is not the case with me.
The values in both channels are the amplitude of the signal in a time slot, so if if they are different that mean when opening this audio file in sound software(like sound forge) the 2 waves should be a little bit different but with me I have different values in these channels and I'm seeing the 2 waves are the same, am I missing something?

Comment: @Maystro, The difference may be so slight that the difference may not be observed from the waveform