# Doing a FFT on a audio file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft, wav

I really would appreciate a solution to my problem. I want to do a FFT on a wav file, with a duration lasting about 10 seconds. My goal is to make a FFT on each second (1-10) and make it visible. This is so I can see what happened in the pervious seconds and see the changes.

Concerning the audio file, I used the program Audacity, in which I took a song and cut out 10 seconds and converted it from mp3-file to a wav-file.

Comment: load in your audio, split it into 10 parts and run `fft` on each one of them, piece of cake - search for "matlab load in audio", "matlab split matrix into 10 parts" and "matlab fft on audio" and come back with a start to your problem

Comment: use matlab to also split the song into segments (no need to do that seperately in audacity)

Comment: Also it can be a good idea to use windows partially overlapped to cut the audio file. In any case try to don't use rectangual windows. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function and http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4844/en/ (just to give you some reference)

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176534/fft-on-samples-of-an-audio-file-in-matlab?rq=1? Can it help?

Comment: In this answer I describe exactly how to build and visualize a spectrogram, which is what you're asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38386589/500207

Comment: @AhmedFasih  Excuse me, this is related to your code, which you provided hre. How do i download this two parts, you mentioned? I wanted to try your code, becaus it looks very promising. I apologize for the late reply, due to various circumstances i couldn't answer earlier.

Comment: stft.m is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fasiha/personal-matlab-namespace/master/%2Barf/stft.m and partition.m is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fasiha/personal-matlab-namespace/master/%2Barf/partition.m (the links in the original answer are embedded in the text)